The scroll is not working in python script
I have written an automated script to open the Control Pannel and get information about the "Programs and Features" I want the Screenshot to be taken of the full output displayed. But for that I need the scrollbar to scroll then take a Screenshot then Again Scroll take a screenshot
import subprocess
import os
import pyautogui
import pygetwindow as gw
from PIL import Image
import time

def maximize_window(title):
    windows = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(title)
    if windows:
        window = windows[0]
        window.maximize()
        window.activate()
        print(f"Maximized and activated window: {title}")
    else:
        print(f"No window found with title: {title}")

def capture_screenshots(folder, prefix, scroll_delay=0.5):
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.makedirs(folder)

    screenshot_index = 0
    previous_screenshot = None
    screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()

    while True:
        # Ensure the window is in focus
        window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle("Programs and Features")[0]
        window.activate()

        screenshot_path = os.path.join(folder, f"{prefix}_{screenshot_index}.png")
        pyautogui.screenshot(screenshot_path)
        print(f"Captured screenshot: {screenshot_path}")

        screenshot_index += 1

        pyautogui.scroll(200)
        time.sleep(scroll_delay)

        current_screenshot = Image.open(screenshot_path)

        # Break if the bottom of the window is reached by comparing the last two screenshots
        if previous_screenshot:
            if list(previous_screenshot.getdata()) == list(current_screenshot.getdata()):
                print("Reached the bottom of the window.")
                break

        previous_screenshot = current_screenshot

def open_programs_and_features():
    try:
        # Open Control Panel directly to Programs and Features
        subprocess.run(['control', 'appwiz.cpl'])

        print("Opened Programs and Features.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while trying to open Programs and Features: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    open_programs_and_features()
    time.sleep(5)

    maximize_window("Programs and Features")
    time.sleep(1)

    capture_screenshots(folder="screenshots", prefix="programs_and_features")


I have written pyautogui.scroll(200) but the application is not scrolling. I also tried pyautogui.scroll(-screen_height) still not working.
